# Android : SQLite check if data exist and update

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

I now sure what i'm doing wrong because java and SQLite for me new. So I need to make check when user is entering new data to DB if data with such "day" and "week_type" exists it need to be updated , else create new row.

```
                    public long creatEntry(int day2, int week_type2,
                String desc2, String place2, String lessnum2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues() ;    
            String update = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE day="+day2+" AND week_type="+week_type;
            Cursor cr = ourDatabase.rawQuery(update, null);
            if(cr!= null){
                cv.put(day, day2);
                cv.put(week_type, week_type2);
                cv.put(desc, desc2);
                cv.put(place, place2);
                cv.put(lessnum, lessnum2);
                return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE,cv, day+ "=" +day2+ " AND "+week_type+ "=" +week_type2, null);
            }
            else{

            cv.put(day, day2);
            cv.put(week_type, week_type2);
            cv.put(desc, desc2);
            cv.put(place, place2);
            cv.put(lessnum, lessnum2);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace. It'll try to insert first, and if it happens to conflict due to a key constraint, it'll delete and insert those values. In your case, these two columns must be [unique](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html). Check it out:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Comment: And what if i want to use Update method ?

Comment: one more , replace change if what columns are equal ?

Comment: Check these links:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Comment: OK, i get this , but in my case to replace 2 columns must be UNIQUE  , so how to make replace ONLy when two of them are UNIQUE ? 
for example :
if  i already have day=1 ,week_type=1 and user enter info with the same 2 columns   day=1 week_type=1.

Comment: I meant UNIQUE in the sense of not having more than one registry where the pair of columns is equal. Consider, for example, that your table has two columns, A and B set as UNIQUE(A, B) with the rows [0, 1] and [2, 4]. You'll be able to insert [1, 1] successfully, because there's no row where A = 1 and B = 1, so it won't conflict. However, if you try to insert [0, 1] or [2, 3], it will fail because it's against the unique constaint which states that the pair [A, B] must be unique.

Comment: "or [2, 3]"  you mean [2,4] ?